# jQuery mobile multiple page different css

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I tried to look this up but I really could find any beautiful solution.
I'm using the jQuery mobile framework and I have multiple pages inside one html file. I'm using different css for some pages (where page is intended as `<div data-role="page">`).

I thought that putting the link to the reference to the css file inside the `<div data-role="page">` would have resolved the conflict problem but it didn't. If I put the link to css file in the second page, the first one will be styled using it as well.

I cant' solve this issue using custom themes because it isn't a problem related to the widgets appearance but it's related to h1,lists and other things that have to be red in some pages but blue in some other pages and so on.

I found 2 solutions to my problem but I feel like they're bit messy. I wish to know if there is some solution to do it in a cleaner way.

The first one is to wrap every selector I want to style with the page id, so that:

main.css

```
h1 {
color : red;
}
```

secondpage.css

```
h1 {
color : red;
}
```

would become

comprehensive.css

```
#main h1 {
    color: red;
}

#secondPage h1{
    color: blue;
}
```

The second solution is to swap the css reference link when changing page.

HTML

```
<head> 
    <link id="cssReference" href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/> 
</head>
```

JQUERY

```
$('#linkToSecondPage').on("click",function(){
    $.mobile.changePage("#secondPage");
    $("link[id='cssReference']").attr('href', 'secondPage.css');     
});
```

**Is there a way to tell jQuery to use different css files for different pages**? My css files are not that big but I'd rather having them separate for maintainability purposes.

Comment: Putting a `<style>` element anywhere in the HTML file will influence the entire HTML file. There is an attribute `scoped` to do exactly what you want, but it's not supported by many browsers yet. Oh, your use of the word "page" confuses things, because HTML files are usually referred to as web pages, so i you go looking for solutions to "per-page css" you may get frustrating results.

Comment: Anyway, my opinion is that your second solution if not very efficient, and I would go with the first. Until `scoped` comes along, there's not much you can do.

Comment: Thank you very much! "per-page css" is giving much more results, I'll look it up right now. I wish I had came up with that without posting. Thank you for suggesting it!!!